# How to add the ellipsis after set the line spacing for UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsmutableattributedstring

I found that UILabel use set the line spacing, he no longer shows the size of the ellipsis even if he is not enough, I would like to know how to add the ellipsis

```
    let message:NSString = "Perhaps you are an average student with average intelligence." 

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str as String)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle();
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, message.length))
    detailLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean rounded corners? If you want perfectly rounded corners add

```
detailLabel.layer.cornerRadius = detailLabel.frame.height / 2
```